# how to push data one bye one array API using python

Tags: python

how to push data one bye one array API using python

```py
import xml
import requests

with open("main.xml") as f:
    data = xml.load(f)
    for line in data:
        r = requests.post('URL',xml=line)
        print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: cam you please give me examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xml.etree.ElementTree

It has various methods for different objective.

Please have a look of link for more details
https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html